# How do you create XML document from reading another XML file using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, dom, xmldom

I'm trying to re-create an xml document.
I'm reading an existing xml document and then trying to re-create it by using C#.

So far I was able to read and create shell of new doc.

I am looping through each child and adding it to the product node.

my xml file (source):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DroneList>
    <product>
        <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
        <modelName>Phantom 3</modelName>
        <estimatedPrice>699</estimatedPrice>
        <flightTime>17 to 20</flightTime>
        <modelSize>Medium</modelSize>   
    </product>
    <product>
        <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
        <modelName>Inspire 1</modelName>
        <estimatedPrice>2899</estimatedPrice>
        <flightTime>18 to 20</flightTime>
        <modelSize>Large</modelSize>
    </product>
</DroneList>
```

Note: There are multiple products under the root with unique item.

### My goal with the C# program is to be able to:

- read the existing products from list
- add them to the new xml document
- add new items to the new xml document
- save xml document as a new xml file

my C# code is below:

```
        private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(XML_FILE_PATH); // load xml data
            XmlDocument newDoc = new XmlDocument(); // create a new xmldocument object to hold new xml data

            txtDisplay.Text += "****Reading Drone List**** \r\n";

            // loaded existing xml data
            XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList children = root.ChildNodes;

            txtDisplay.Text += "****Showing Existing Data**** \r\n children: " + children.Count + "\r\n";

            for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++)
            {
                XmlElement product = newDoc.CreateElement("product");
                product.SetAttribute("productId", i.ToString());

                foreach (XmlNode child in children)
                {

                    XmlElement manufacturer = newDoc.CreateElement("manufacturer");
                    XmlElement modelName = newDoc.CreateElement("modelName");
                    XmlElement estimatedPrice = newDoc.CreateElement("estimatedPrice");
                    XmlElement flightTime = newDoc.CreateElement("flightTime");
                    XmlElement modelSize = newDoc.CreateElement("modelSize");

                    manufacturer.InnerText = child["manufacturer"].InnerText;
                    modelName.InnerText = child["modelName"].InnerText;
                    estimatedPrice.InnerText = child["estimatedPrice"].InnerText;
                    flightTime.InnerText = child["flightTime"].InnerText;
                    modelSize.InnerText = child["modelSize"].InnerText;

                    product.AppendChild(manufacturer);
                    product.AppendChild(modelName);
                    product.AppendChild(estimatedPrice);
                    product.AppendChild(flightTime);
                    product.AppendChild(modelSize);
                }
            }



            txtDisplay.Text += "****Showing new doc so far**** \r\n";

            txtDisplay.Text += newDoc.InnerXml + "\r\n"; // display xml in the textbox

            //txtDisplay.Text += newRoot.InnerText + "\r\n";

            txtDisplay.Text += "****Adding New Data**** \r\n";

            

            for (int i = 5; i < 5; i++)
            {
                //
            }

            XmlElement newRoot = newDoc.CreateElement("DroneList"); // the root element is <roster>
            newDoc.AppendChild(newRoot);
            XmlDeclaration xmlDec = newDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
            newDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDec, newRoot); // insert before the root element

            newDoc.Save("..\\..\\..\\new_drones.xml");

        }
```

### Desired XML outcome:

new xml file (target)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DroneList>
    <!-- existing products from source file -->
    <product>
        <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
        <modelName>Phantom 3</modelName>
        <estimatedPrice>699</estimatedPrice>
        <flightTime>17 to 20</flightTime>
        <modelSize>Medium</modelSize>   
    </product>
    <product>
        <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
        <modelName>Inspire 1</modelName>
        <estimatedPrice>2899</estimatedPrice>
        <flightTime>18 to 20</flightTime>
        <modelSize>Large</modelSize>
    </product>
    <!-- new products added through C# program (Hard coded) -->
    <product>
        <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
        <modelName>Inspire 1</modelName>
        <estimatedPrice>2899</estimatedPrice>
        <flightTime>18 to 20</flightTime>
        <modelSize>Large</modelSize>
    </product>
    <product>
        <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
        <modelName>Inspire 1</modelName>
        <estimatedPrice>2899</estimatedPrice>
        <flightTime>18 to 20</flightTime>
        <modelSize>Large</modelSize>
    </product>
    <product>
        <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
        <modelName>Inspire 1</modelName>
        <estimatedPrice>2899</estimatedPrice>
        <flightTime>18 to 20</flightTime>
        <modelSize>Large</modelSize>
    </product>
</DroneList>
```

Comment: Please add to your question a desired output XML. Overall, it sounds like a task for XSLT.

Comment: if it was me I would (1) de-serialize to c# object, (2) write code to add to object's list, (3) de-serialize back to xml.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I've updated the question with desired outcome.

Comment: This kind of thing is so much easier with XSLT, which was purpose-designed for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, XSLT is made by design to transform input XML into output XML, or other textual formats.

Please try the following XSLT based solution.

The XSLT takes the last **product** element and multiplies it 4 times.
The rest of the input XML stays the same.

The c# code below is a generic boilerplate code for XSLT transformations.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DroneList>
    <product>
        <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
        <modelName>Phantom 3</modelName>
        <estimatedPrice>699</estimatedPrice>
        <flightTime>17 to 20</flightTime>
        <modelSize>Medium</modelSize>
    </product>
    <product>
        <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
        <modelName>Inspire 1</modelName>
        <estimatedPrice>2899</estimatedPrice>
        <flightTime>18 to 20</flightTime>
        <modelSize>Large</modelSize>
    </product>
</DroneList>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product[last()]">
        <xsl:variable name="product">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="(//node())[4 &gt;= position()]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$product"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DroneList>
  <product>
    <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
    <modelName>Phantom 3</modelName>
    <estimatedPrice>699</estimatedPrice>
    <flightTime>17 to 20</flightTime>
    <modelSize>Medium</modelSize>
  </product>
  <product>
    <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
    <modelName>Inspire 1</modelName>
    <estimatedPrice>2899</estimatedPrice>
    <flightTime>18 to 20</flightTime>
    <modelSize>Large</modelSize>
  </product>
  <product>
    <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
    <modelName>Inspire 1</modelName>
    <estimatedPrice>2899</estimatedPrice>
    <flightTime>18 to 20</flightTime>
    <modelSize>Large</modelSize>
  </product>
  <product>
    <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
    <modelName>Inspire 1</modelName>
    <estimatedPrice>2899</estimatedPrice>
    <flightTime>18 to 20</flightTime>
    <modelSize>Large</modelSize>
  </product>
  <product>
    <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
    <modelName>Inspire 1</modelName>
    <estimatedPrice>2899</estimatedPrice>
    <flightTime>18 to 20</flightTime>
    <modelSize>Large</modelSize>
  </product>
</DroneList>
```

**c#**

```
oid Main()
{
   const string SOURCEXMLFILE = @"e:\Temp\input.xml";
   const string XSLTFILE = @"e:\Temp\process.xslt";
   const string OUTPUTXMLFILE = @"e:\temp\output.xml";

   try
   {
      XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();

      using (XmlReader src = XmlReader.Create(SOURCEXMLFILE))
      {
         XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
         xslt.Load(XSLTFILE, new XsltSettings(true, true), new XmlUrlResolver());

         XmlWriterSettings settings = xslt.OutputSettings.Clone();
         settings.IndentChars = "\t";
         // to remove BOM
         settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

         using (XmlWriter result = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUTXMLFILE, settings))
         {
            xslt.Transform(src, xslArg, result, new XmlUrlResolver());
            result.Close();
         }
      }
      Console.WriteLine("File '{0}' has been generated.", OUTPUTXMLFILE);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: @Yizhak I need to only do this with C#. I cannot use XSLT or any other approach other than XML DOM and systematically breaking it down using elements and nodes.

Comment: XSLT is a part of the .Net Framework. So what's the problem?